# problema con labels c# formulario

Tags: c#, formularios

Tengo un problema que no pensé tener, la cosa es que tengo un formulario donde debo mostrar en un label la suma acumulativa de un código

Digamos que tengo un TextBox donde cada numero que meto se suman acumulativamente, los cuales son  (4, 5, 6) cada suma que hace mi codigo se debe mostrar en un label pero aqui es donde me mete un problema raro

// el contador esta seteado en 0 desde que el formulario se carga

```
        contador = contador + Convert.ToInt32(txtPrecio.Text);
        lblcontardor.Text = contador.ToString();
```

me sale un error que dice "System.FormatException: 'La cadena de entrada no tiene el formato correcto.'
"

Comment: Tu escribes en el textbox 4,5,6 todo junto?

Comment: El contador esta a  0 pero..que hay en `txtPrecio` al inicio de tu aplicación?

Comment: Te recomiendo que validez, que lo que estas ingresando en el TextBox sea un numero, de igual forma si el textbox esta vacío o null, no vas a poder hacer parse de ese valor como numero.

Comment: para Japv se ingresa uno por uno

Comment: TheOligarch, el boton que ejecuta la suma acumulativa se habilita cuando el usuario ingre solo numeros

Comment: Pikoh el inicio esta vacio el txtPrecio, pero como le comente a TheOligarch el boton que ejecuta la suma acumulativa se habilita cuando en el txtPrecio esta solo con Numeros

Comment: Entras valores de coma digamos 2.37?